# Unregistering a Broadcast in a Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am using a Local Broadcast to start playing music by my Service once the playlist has been asynchronously fetched. It works well but I have some interrogations about how & when to unregister the broadcast receiver.
In my implementation,

```
unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver);
```

is called in onDestroy().

So I have two questions about this :

- Am I guaranteed that onDestroy will be called, even if the application crashes ?
- Can it be useful to unregister a broadcast receiver as soon as it is not useful anymore in terms of memory/cpu ? This particular receiver is only needed at most once during each execution of the app (the playlist can be loaded before the service is started, in that case I do not need the broadcast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No, you're never guaranteed. But you can *guarantee* to yourself that every error is checked/catched and handled appropriately in your code.
- It can be useful. Unregister if it serves no purpose, what could be wrong with that?

Comment: +1. It's definitely advisable to unregister the receiver. I once ran into a problem with apparently random crashes, but found out that it was caused by a receiver that wasn't unregistered.